# Plot of a function defined on a differentiabl manifold

Tags: plotting

I'm following  a course of Math and I would like to have a Plot of a 3D function defined over a CountorPlot. I used the command of 'Plot3D' to define the domain of a function but the region where the function f is defined is a differential manifold. There is an example:

f:3 x^2 - 2 y

manifold: x^3 - 3 x^2 y + y^2 - 1 == 0

I tried to visualize the intersection between the graphs using this code:

```
  aaa = ContourPlot3D[
  x^3 - 3 x^2 y + y^2 - 1 == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 
  10}, PlotPoints -> 100]

  bbb = Plot3D[ 3 x^2 - 2 y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]

  Show[aaa, bbb]
```

Answer (score 3):

use `Mesh` and `MeshFunctions` tricks.

```
f = 3 x^2 - 2 y;
g = x^3 - 3 x^2 y + y^2 - 1;
Plot3D[f, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, g], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thickness[Large], Red], PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Combining your original approach with that of cvgmt

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f = 3 x^2 - 2 y;
g = x^3 - 3 x^2 y + y^2 - 1;

Legended[
 Show[
  ContourPlot3D[g == 0,
   {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10},
   PlotPoints -> 100,
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Blue]],
  Plot3D[f,
   {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
   PlotPoints -> 100,
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Green],
   MeshFunctions ->
    Function[{x, y, z}, g],
   Mesh -> {{0}},
   MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}]],
 SwatchLegend[
  {Opacity[0.5, Green], Opacity[0.5, Blue], Red},
  {"f", "g==0", "Intersection"}]]
```

[image]